# Is there non-daemon FTP server application fot Mac OS? (like MAMP)

Tags: ftp, macos, mamp

I'm finding an non-daemon, interactive-mode only, portable(moveable) FTP server for Mac OS X.
Like MAMP.

This will be used temporarily for local development only. Not for service.
Just file listing and serving(download) features required. Complex features like account management or SSL are not required.

This should be run as an UI application, and should not depend on system setting. Whole server should possible to be moved with only folder copying.

Is there a solution like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Woof](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/woof.html) is a web not ftp server. Minimal and almost trivial to use. Depending on you use case it might work for you.

Comment: Wow it seems to be a better solution. Thanks!